# Circular question dependencies - question links to dupe, dupe links back to question

Tags: discussion

The odds are too high that my guess at the appropriate action will not be the best.  Maybe this has come up before.

Here's an **Apr 9**, 2013 question:

#### [Add Application to Startup (Registry)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913202)

Here's an **Apr 10**, 2013 question from the **same user**:

#### [Save Me Simple Add to Startup via Registry [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935564)

- The Apr 10 question is marked as a duplicate of the Apr 9 question.
- The Apr 9 question's [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15937702/16287) is "See the answer I gave to your other [Apr 10] question"

What's the best practice for this unusual situation?

Comment: An answering program trying to find the answer to this question will experience a stack overflow. Ah, the irony ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An answer that just says that the answer is on another SO question isn't a valid answer, and should be flagged as Not An Answer.

If the C/C++ community feels that the answer to the currently closed question is of higher value than the other answer to the open question, the closed question can be reopened and the open question closed as a duplicate of the currently closed question.  A mod or a user with a gold badge in the relevant tags would be able to do both unilaterally.  If the community feels that the answer to the open question is the best answer, then there's nothing that needs to be done at all.

If both answers are considered particularly valuable, with neither being sufficient on its own, you can flag the questions to be merged.

Comment: "flag the questions to be merged" - that would be a typed *moderator intervention* message?

Comment: @DrewDormann animuson already merged it now.